# Access another models value within a view, simple but complex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple problem, but finding the solution is NOT that simple.

I have two models, Person, Skill
Person has many skills
Skills belong to person

In the database, Person table has a skill_id which takes the id from the Skills table as foreign key.

In the view I am trying to list the skills for that Person by name, I can get them by id, but how can I retrieve the name field from the Skills table.

Person.html(view)

```
<p>Current skills for: <b><%= "#{ @person.name }" -%></b></p>   

<% @people.each do |p| %>  
    <p>Age: <%= "#{p.age}" %></p>  
    <p><%= "#{p.start_date}" %></p>  
    <p><%= "#{p.skill_id}" %></p>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly by indenting it with 4 spaces or by using \` inline.

Comment: Skill is supposed to bear the user_id: this is were you set belongs_to

Comment: `Person has_many :skills` means that Person is the Parent in the association. So how can you set `skill_id` as foreign key in Person model. Rather Skill model should have the Person as a reference. Actually this is a many-to-many scenario. A particular skill can be shared by many people. So you might re-consider the database structure. :) You can try using a join model to represent this, as follows:

Comment: In Person model `has_many :person_skills has_many :skills, :through => :person_skills`. In Skill Model `has_many :person_skills has_many :persons, :through => :person_skills`. In PersonSkill Model `belongs_to => :person belongs_to :skill`

Answer (score 2):

You say you've got `has_many :skills`. but then you go on to say that you've got a `skill_id` on a the `persons` table, which is incongruent. Which is it that you want?

Do you want a person to have a single specific skill in which case then what you've got now database-wise is fine, but model wise is not. The `Person` model in this case would have to have `belongs_to :skill` and the `Skill` model would have to have `has_many :people`

The other possible way around I can think that you'd want it is that a person [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) `:skills` and a skill `has_and_belongs_to_many :people`. This will allow many people to have many skills, which is what I truly think you want. Then in the view, you can do this:

```
<% people.each do |p| %>
  <h2><%= p.name %>'s skills</h2>
  <% p.skills.each do |skill| %>
    <%= skill.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So which is it? Your question says one thing and then the polar opposite which is greatly confusing. I hope this answer will help you make the right choice.

Comment: -1 @Ryan If there is a situation where `Person has many skills` then the `people.each` will give you a person and `person.skills` will give you an array of skills of that person. Hence you can't do `p.skills.name`

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be trying to search the skills table by person_id.

Comment: So I want it to, get all the people, for each person, retrieve all of their skills (usually more than 1), but retrieve their skills by name, not id.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `skills` WHERE (`skills`.people_id = 1) - but of course the skills table has no people id, just id, and name.

Comment: @Rohit: I've re-written the answer. If you'd be kind enough to review and remove the down-vote, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Thank all of you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: I managed to get it working, and yes it was a many to many relationship which had to be bridged by another table. I have another question, suppose the Person table is linked to a Department table, 1 department has many people. When looping the @people |p|, how can I retrieve the department name, again I can get the ID, as the People table has a foreign key of department_id.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @people.each do |p| %>
  <% p.skills.each do |s| %>
    <%= s.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tried something like that and now tried your solution, but I get the following error in the view:

Comment: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'skills.people_id' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `skills` WHERE (`skills`.people_id = 1) )  it seems to be introducing the people_id, instead of the skill_id??

Comment: Ive added a :foreign_key => "skill_id" to the people model, still no luck.

Comment: You shouldn't add "skill_id" to the people model if it's a 1 to n person-to-skills relationship. You should add person_id field to Skill instead  and specify "belongs_to :person" in Skill model and "has_many :skills" in Person model (although it's better to rewrite it as n to m relationship, as different people can have similar skills)

Answer (score 0):

You current model design does not support requirement, i.e.

**Skill belongs to multiple Person**

**Person has many skills**

This is good case for many-to-many association. You have introduce a bridge table to hold the association.

```
class Person
  has_many :person_skills
  has_many :skills, :through => :person_skills
end

class Skill
  has_many :person_skills
  has_many :person, :through => :person_skills
end

# person_skills table with person_id and skill_id columns
class PersonSkill
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

To get the skills of a person by name:

```
@person.skills.find_all_by_name("foo")
@person.skills.all(:conditions => ["name LIKE ?", "foo%"])
```